# issues with v-ons tag don't which doesn't work

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm trying to learn **onsenui** with **Vue. Js.**

I'm using the cdn link to use onsen-vue.
The **ons** tag works but the v-ons tag don't.
The error I'm getting says

> custom tag not defined.

For eg v-ons button doesn't works but ons button works.
I have simply created html file to test it. 
I can also see onsen-vue(2.4) is loaded in the resources
I have added cdn for Vue.js (2.4)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [working  example](https://jsfiddle.net/ks2at34L/) of HelloWorld from onsen [docs](https://onsen.io/v2/guide/vue/#hello-world-with-vue)

It uses cdn versions of vue-onsenui@2.4 and vue@2.4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@2.8.1/css/onsenui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@2.8.1/css/onsen-css-components.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.0/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui@2.8.1/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-onsenui@2.4.0/dist/vue-onsenui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<template id="main-page">
    <v-ons-page>
        <v-ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Title</div>
        </v-ons-toolbar>

        <p style="text-align: center">
            <v-ons-button @click="$ons.notification.alert('Hello World!')">
                Click me!
            </v-ons-button>
        </p>
    </v-ons-page>
</template>

<div id="app"></div>

<script>
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        template: '#main-page'
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uncaught type error Object . values is not a function and no toolbar or button displays only text can be seen .Ty

Comment: @user8227740 Can you try with `vue-onsenui@2.4.1`?

Comment: @Fran Dios I can try and tell .According to below link my browser , chrome doesn't support object.values https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Comment: @Fran Dios   Could you please help me with below problem.                                          My onsenui-vue app runs in browser but when I run on android through cordova I get Uncaught reference error weak map is not defined  And no toolbar or button is seen just text is displayed. I have added the onsen lib in www folder of my cordova app.I don't use monaca or Web pack.What is the correct way of adding it in cordova